# Is there a way to make another page without having another html extension?

Tags: javascript, html

Got an assignment where I have to make different pages for a website. Right now I have multiple html files where I link to each time to open pages. For example
Bagel, and Bagel.html is another file. Is there a better and efficient way to do this?

Comment: I'd go back to the books if I were you. This site is not for getting assignments answers. Also this looks like something core you should understand before moving forward.

Comment: Suggestion: provide a concise sample of what you are trying to solve and concise evidence of what you have done so far. The question as written now is too vague for any of us to offer any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a .htaccess file (that is if I understand what you are trying to do.)

You can learn how to do this here: https://www.geekshosted.com/Blog/how-to-remove-html-from-your-url/

Remember so not forget to remove the .htm or .html from your bagel.html while doing this. Hope this works.